# How to run a .py file in IDLE which is in a different folder other than where Python is installed?

Tags: python

I am trying to run a .py script using IDLE which is in a different folder say D:\Python\Practice whereas my python is installed in C:\Python.

I changed the directory to D:\Python\Practice where the script was present through os.chdir command. Then I executed python xyz.py but it is throwing error.

```
import os
os.chdir("D:\Python\Practice")
python xyz.py
```

> Syntax Error: Invalid Syntax

Comment: open the IDLE, open your .py file via the new IDLE (File > open file - xyz.py) and run the script, you dont need to write a new script to run the other script

Comment: I understand that but I wanted to know how I can execute it with command line.

Comment: "python xyz.py" is invalid syntax

Comment: I see, I had similar issues in the past. In my case it was a one time thing, so I just moved my .py script into the Python main folder and then ran it, that was my workaround

Answer (score 0):

Using Windows CLI, you can navigate to your folder and execute the script as following:

```
\> D:

D:\>cd D:\Python\Practice

D:\Python\Practice\>python xyz.py
```

Or simply give the full path of your file in the python command wherever you are:

`>python D:\Python\Practice\xyz.py`